# arp spoofing in VMware ESXi

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I have a VMware ESXi server and I want to create two virtual machines with specific  public IP addresses.
Is it possible for the 2 virtual machines to sniff each other's traffic ? If so how can it be prevented ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your VMs are just as susceptible to attacks as physical attacks, even from other VMs on the same network. There are several methods to isolate and protect your VMs from each other as stated here [ESXi vCenter Security Doc](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-security-guide.pdf). (see doc for more info here, lots of good ideas you can use):

- Adding firewall protection to your virtual network by installing and configuring host-based firewalls on some or all of its virtual machines.
- Keeping different virtual machine zones within a host on different network segments.

  - Use separate physical network adapters for virtual machine zones to ensure that the zones are isolated.
  - Set up virtual local area networks (VLANs) to help safeguard your network.